# Error in app windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I uploaded an app to windows store, I managed to publish me but when installing, I get an error.

I leave the link there if you can tell me where is the error:
http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/es-es/app/beers-challenge/2480e2a0-7840-487d-9f79-d4a84df8270c#

[image]

Comment: I don't get the error.

Comment: Check [this](http://atechjourney.com/how-to-fix-error-0x80240017-in-windows-8-and-8-1.html/) out. It appears to be related to a corrupted registry.